# Preview Doesn't Match Live View

Tags: bug, code-formatting

This question ([Fatal error when try add snippets code on functions.php Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65643989/fatal-error-when-try-add-snippets-code-on-functions-php-wordpress)) had HTML in it that caused the preview to display subtly different (after `Complemento`) than the actual question.

**Preview:**
[image: preview]

**Question:**
[image: question]

I put the HTML in a code block and it worked but strange that it displays correctly (or correcter) in preview mode.

Comment: That is not a bug. The editor didn't think it was part of the code so it treated it like normal html tags and rendered accordingly.

Comment: That is inconsistent behavior though. The preview did not preview as it displayed live.